# Get count days in current year by day name or day id

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
    name  id
----------------
    Mon   1
    Thu   2
    Wen   3
    Thr   4
    Fri   5
    Sat   6
    San   7
```

How get count day where id in eg.  (1,2,3,4) and year is 2021

The result should be 208.

Comment: Could you provide the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is 208 for year 2021.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     year AS (SELECT &par_year year FROM DUAL),
  3     calendar
  4     AS
  5        (    SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE (y.year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy') + LEVEL - 1 datum
  6               FROM year y
  7         CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
  8                      ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (TO_DATE (y.year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'), 12)
  9                    - TRUNC (TO_DATE (y.year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'))
 10  SELECT SUM (CASE
 11                 WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (c.datum, 'd')) IN (1,
 12                                                             2,
 13                                                             3,
 14                                                             4)
 15                 THEN
 16                    1
 17                 ELSE
 18                    0
 19              END) result
 20    FROM calendar c;
Enter value for par_year: 2021

    RESULT
----------
       208

SQL> /
Enter value for par_year: 2020

    RESULT
----------
       210

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `YEAR` CTE contains year you're interested in
- `CALENDAR` CTE creates all dates in that particular year
- `SUM` function conditionally adds 1 if `TO_CHAR(datum, 'd')` is 1, 2, 3 or 4
- that's all